# How to detect the keyboard is native keyboard or third party keyboard in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I get a problem to detect native keyboard or third party keyboard in ionic 3, according to the pentest that third party keyboard is so danger, so I need to detect a mobile phone uses native keyboard or third party keyboard in ionic 3.

Can you show me how to detect third party keyboard in ionic 3 ?

Thanks.